# Создать поток из member function, если std::mutex также является member variable

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++20, mutex

К сожалению, если попытаться сделать

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class A
{
public:
    void foo() noexcept
    {
        //code
    }

private:
    std::mutex m{};
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::thread(&A::foo, a);
}
```

код не соберётся. Всё из-за того, что `std::mutex` находится в классе. Если его убрать, то код собирается. Почему так происходит? Как мне запустить поток от мембер функции, когда у меня мьютекс находится внутри класса?

Comment: А в чем смысл держать его как член класса? при том, что мьютекс не копируется? Кстати, проблема у вас не в самом мьютексе как таковом,  в том, что он делает ваш класс некопируемым.

Comment: Вы мой спаситель. Пожалуйста, напишите ответ, чтобы я его пометил

Comment: Вам следует прочитать про аргументы конструктора `thread` и про его деструктор. И в мьютексе или некопируемом классе тут как раз проблем нет, проблема в том, что вы передаете не тот аргумент.

Answer (score 2):

Было

```cpp
std::thread(&A::foo, a);
```

А надо

```cpp
std::thread(&A::foo, &a);
```

Comment: Или `std::ref(a)`.